# std::variant with forward declaration

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm working on a simple state machine similar to [this](https://www.bfilipek.com/2019/06/fsm-variant-game.html).

I'm trying to encode my states in separate classes which looks like:

```
// class StateA; (1)
// class StateB; (2)

using State = std::variant<StateA, StateB>;

class StateA {
  State handle(/* some params */) { return StateB(); };
};

class StateB {
  State handle(/* some params */){ return StateA(); };
};
```

Now my variant knows nothing about StateA and StateB, which results into `use of undeclared identifier 'StateA'`. If I uncomment (1) and (2) and have a forward declaration, then I get `incomplete type 'StateA' used in type trait expression`

Is there a way to have a variant with classes, that has variant in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make sure that both of your `variant` members are complete types at the point where you use it, for example by moving the definitions for `handle` methods outside of your classes:

```
#include <variant>

class StateA;
class StateB;

using State = std::variant<StateA, StateB>;

class StateA {
    State handle(/* some params */);
};

class StateB {
    State handle(/* some params */);
};

State StateA::handle() { return StateB(); }

State StateB::handle() { return StateA(); }
```

Comment: Looks like that's some kind of a sorcery I can't fully understand at that time, but this works:) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use dynamic polymorphism as a more convenient design: store `std::unique_ptr<State>` and use `std::make_unique<StateX>()` to initialize it with a `StateX` derived from `State` where the latter is an abstract base class.

`std::unique_ptr` allows forward-declared types but `std::make_unique` still requires the trick from the accepted answer as it needs `StateX`'s size and constructor.